# HTTP to HTTPS redirect withouth specifying hostname?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, http-redirect

I'm looking to redirect any web request to HTTP to HTTPS in apache and I have a working solution that I have added to my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhostname.com
        Redirect / https://myhostname.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

this solution however is host-name dependent and I would like to know if there's a host-name independent method. 
I tried using `${HOST_NAME}` but it didn't work I guess the variable needs to be set before hand.

Comment: Did you try the above? It's outside the VirtualHost container, so it should be universal for all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myhostname.com
</VirtualHost>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This redirect your whole site, means every http request will be redirected, is this what you want?

Comment: in this case I would still need to use `ServerName myhostname.com` I'm wondering if there's a way where I can just tell it to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS without the need to specify my "myhostname.com"

Comment: Did you tried the above?

It's outside the VirtualHost container, so it should be universal for all request.

Comment: it works thank you so much!, so let's see of I understand what's going on:  if a condition that says if the request is "HTTPS" is off then the request is re-written with https.. is this correct?

Comment: what does the (.*) do after RewriteRule?

Comment: the (.*) is not after, but before ... rule reading is: RewriteRule REQUEST REWRITE-TO  , the asterisk just means take the whole request as is  and rewrite it to the defined rule